# How do I utilize the full power of the CPU? Why is its full power not used when needed?

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, overclocking

The CPU frequency is 2799 MHz even though the maximum frequncy is 3100 MHz. The System Monitor still shows 100% Utilization.

- How do I force the system to use the full capacity?**
- Why is the system not using the full capacity of the CPU?**

[image: CPU frequency is 2799 MHz even though the maximum is 3100. The System Monitor still shows 100% Utilization]

*Note: My CPU/motherboard is not overclock-able*

Comment: Check your bios settings - that a lower clock speed has not been selected, but also look for options to enable/disable OS control of the clock, and power management options.

Comment: @kurja - That isn't the problem. See my answer.

Comment: @kurja As mentioned in the question, my CPU is not overclock-able so such options will not be available at the BIOS settings page. The model is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz

Comment: @NaveenDennis - Now that you have provided your CPU model, I will update my answer to address your specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided your CPU model, I can only guess at which CPU you might have based on the clock speeds you provided. My best guess is you have an `Intel Core i5 2300`.

Assuming that is actually your CPU, the explanation is quite simple. As you can see on the [Intel ARK website for the i5 2300](https://ark.intel.com/products/52206/Intel-Core-i5-2300-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz), the CPU can only reach 3.1GHz by using Turbo Boost.

Turbo Boost is subject to some limitations, however:

- The CPU will only turbo boost if the thermal situation permits
- Only one core can turbo boost to 3.1GHz.

Thus, assuming that your thermals are okay, the reason that your CPU is not turbo boosting in your workload is because you are using all four cores; and because the CPU cannot turbo boost all four cores, the CPU is running at its max non-turbo frequency of 2.8GHz.

Comment: Does the behavior with the change in model, specifically with mine? (I think it is appropriate for my model as well).

Comment: @NaveenDennis  - It changes it only a little bit. I will be updating my answer, I just haven't gotten around to it yet :D